# finite satisfiability

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

There is an implication that I can't quite understand:

Given a set $\Sigma$ of well-formed-formulas and a well-formed-formula $\tau$, if $\Sigma_0\cup \{\tau\}$ is satisfiable for every finite $\Sigma_0\subseteq\Sigma$, then $\Sigma\cup\{\tau\}$ is finitely satisfiable

But I don't understand. Isn't the converse of the statement true, because finite satisfiability of $\Sigma\cup\{\tau\}$ implies the finite satisfiability of $\Sigma$?:

Given a set $\Sigma$ of well-formed-formulas and a well-formed-formula $\tau$, if $\Sigma\cup\{\tau\}$ is finitely satisfiable, then $\Sigma_0\cup \{\tau\}$ is satisfiable for every finite $\Sigma_0\subseteq\Sigma$

Comment: What do you mean by "finitely satisfiable"?

Comment: A set of well-formed-formulas is finitely satisfiable iff all the subsets of it are satisfiable.

Comment: Okay, then the first statement follows from the compactness theorem (a set of sentences is satisfiable if and only if all finite subsets of said set are satisfiable). The converse statement is also true, but trivially so and this is _not_ a contradiction to the first one being true.

Comment: @Watercrystal Can you prove the first implication?

Comment: The first part implies that $\Sigma \cup \{\tau\}$ is satisfiable. If a set of FO sentences is satisfiable, then so is every subset of said set.

Comment: Oh right! I learned that the hard way! Thank you.

Comment: @Watercrystal Slow down a minute. Actually, the first part doesn't imply that $\Sigma\cup\{\tau\}$ is satisfiable. It does when $\Sigma$ is finite, but in case of an infinite set, it only tells that $\Sigma_0\cup\{\tau\}$ is satisfiable for a finite subset $\Sigma_0$. It's not the case that finite subsets of $\Sigma\cup\{\tau\}$ are satisfiable. it's the case that $\Sigma_0\cup\{\tau\}$ is satisfiable for a finite subset $\Sigma_0$; $\{\tau\}$ is always included.

Comment: No, your statement reads "For every finite $\Sigma_0$ the set $\{\tau\} \cup \Sigma_0$" is satisfiable. That also implies that every finite subset of $\Sigma \cup \{\tau\}$ is satisfiable (as we can always drop $\tau$ and without making stuff unsatisfiable). From there on out it is a straightforward application of the compactness theorem.

Comment: @Watercrystal I still don't follow you: What do you mean by "as we can always drop τ and without making stuff unsatisfiable"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115366/discussion-between-watercrystal-and-kkkk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a set smaller only makes it more easy to satisfy: if $\Delta\subseteq\Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ is satisfiable then $\Delta$ is also satisfiable.

---

Here's how this applies to your question in detail:

Suppose we have $\Sigma,\tau$ as in the OP and let $X\subseteq\Sigma\cup\{\tau\}$ be finite; we want to show that $X$ is satisfiable. Let $\Sigma_0=X\cap \Sigma$, and let $X'=\Sigma_0\cup\{\tau\}$. Clearly $X'\supseteq X$ since in fact $X'=X\cup\{\tau\}$; moreover, by hypothesis on $\Sigma$ and $\tau$ we know that $X'$ is satisfiable (since $\Sigma_0$ is finite, being a subset of the finite set $X$).

So we know that the set $X$ which we care about has a satisfiable superset - but that means that $X$ itself is satisfiable.